# My JIRA Github integration only syncs every 60 minutes

Tags: git, github, jira

I have setup my Online JIRA DVCS connector with Github and smart commits enabled. I've used the instructions available here: [Linking Bitbucket and GitHub accounts to JIRA](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Linking+Bitbucket+and+GitHub+accounts+to+JIRA)

My Github Application Homepage URL: company.atlassian.net

My Github Callback URL: company.atlassian.net/plugins/servlet/oauth/authorize

Whenever our team makes a Git commit, it doesn't update/transition the ticket right away. Instead it takes up to an hour for the change to take place. I can also manually run the sync from the JIRA Admin page to get the update to happen.

Has anyone gotten this to update JIRA tickets in real time?

Answer (score 1):

Jira should be updating the tickets in real time if everything is working correctly. It uses webhooks to get notified at the time of the commit. If it is only updating every hour then there is probably a problem with the webhooks so it is falling back to hourly polling.

The jira dvcs connector troubleshooting guide might give you a suggestion as to how to resolve this.
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRACLOUD/Troubleshoot+the+DVCS+Connector